# python SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = self.variable

Tags: python, oop, sqlite, python-3.6

I am trying to SELECT the data in the column base on the given arg.
but an error appear **Incorrect number of bindings supplied**

```
class TheClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.con = connect('mydb.db')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def getonedata(self, text):
        self.variable = text
        self.cur.execute("""SELECT username, age, password FROM usertbl WHERE username =?""",(self.variable))
        self.result = self.cur.fetchone()
        return self.result

    def getoneresult(self, text):

        for row in self.getonedata(text):
            self.row1 = row[0]
            self.row2 = row[1]
            self.row3 = row[2]

            print("{} {} {}".format(self.row1, self.row2, self.row3))
app = TheClass()
app.getonedata('IgiveUP')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to supply parameters as a tuple to the `execute` method, and in Python, a single-item tuple has to be specified with an additional comma:

```
self.cur.execute("""SELECT username, age, password FROM usertbl WHERE username =?""",(self.variable,))
```

Comment: Thanks it fixed it!!!. but an error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable: but the datatype in DB is Varchar(255)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yeah this ->Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/learnpython/get_sqltable.py", line 25, in <module>
    app.getoneresult('pokemon')
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/learnpython/get_sqltable.py", line 18, in getoneresult
    self.row1 = row[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `fetchone()` returns the values of the next row as one sequence, and yet in `getoneresult()` you're treating it as a list of multiple rows. You should use `fetchall()` instead of `fetchone()` if you want to treat the result as multiple rows. Or, if there is always only one row returned, you should simply assign the result to a tuple of variables. e.g. `username, age, password = self.getonedata(text)`

Comment: the error now gone, i just changed "fetchone()" to "fetchall()". thanks